# Count the frequency of a list of words within another list

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nlp, nested-lists

I have a list of lists which I want to see the frequency in a sentence:

```
words = [plates, will]
sentence = [the, plates, will, still, shift, and, the, clouds, will, still, spew,]
```

I want to count how many times a set of word has been mentioned in a list.
So from the list `words` [plates,will] is mentioned just 1 time in the sentence

I have a whole column which I want to iterate.

Desirable output is:

| sentence | word | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [the, plates, will, still, shift, and, the, clouds, will, still, spew,] | [plates ,will] | 1 |
| [the, plates, will, still, shift, and, the, clouds, will, still, spew,] | [still, spew] | 1 |

I have tried this:

```
for word in word:
    if word in sentence:
        counts[word] += 1
    else:
        counts[word] = 1
```

also

```
[[word.count() for word in b if word in row] for row in b]
```

Any help for the right output?

Comment: there are no strings in your lists ... at all. [ask] && [mre].

Comment: `for word in word:` makes NO sense.

Comment: What frequency do you want to see?
Word frequency (e.g. how many times "plates" is mentioned) or combination of words frequency (e.g. how many times "plates, will" is mentioned).
Please clarify this since on the first example the "will" is mentioned more than once.

Comment: @Jake No - they got _variable names_  in their lists - that are not defined. No strings at all.  A string lists `looks_like = ["T","h","i","s"]` or `like = ['T','h','i','s']`

Comment: I meant df['word''] @PatrickArtner

Answer (score 0):

This is not inline but it does the job I understood you asked for.

```py
words = ["plates", "will"]
sentence = ["the", "plates", "will", "still", "shift", "and"]

count = 0
# Go through each word in the sentence
for si in range(len(sentence) - len(words)):
    match = True
    # Compare if the following words match
    for wi, word in enumerate(words):
        # Break if one word is wrong
        if sentence[si + wi] != word:
            match = False
            break
    if match:
        count +=1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that soultion with Counter is simplier.

```
from collections import Counter

words = ['plates', 'will']
sentence = ['the', 'plates', 'will', 'still', 'shift', 'and', 'the', 'clouds', 'will', 'still', 'spew',]

word_counts = Counter(sentence)

for word in words:
    print(word, word_counts[word])
```